# Edit Widget Add attachments only shows when is made, not when making

Tags: arcgis-server, editing, fields-attributes

So i post my question here because it didnt recieved any answers on Stackoverflow.

Hello i have some difficulties, 
Let me see what i want to do with some pictures and code:

I want to add some features with the edit widgets, when i do i get this:

[image]

But i need to get: add attachment under 'oprmerking',

When i click on the one i just added, i get to see the add attachment button, but i need to add the attachment when i create the new object:
This is a picture of it:

[image]

There you see the show attachment, and there you can, if there is no attachment, add an attachment.

Also, when i sometimes press one of the functions, or another widget, and i click on the little green thing and only this shows: this is weird right?

[image]

Anyways, maybe you know what i'm doing wrong, here's some of my code from the

```
private function createFieldInspectors(editableLayerName:String,

editableLayerFieldNames:Array, 
editableLayerFieldLabels:Array,

editableLayerHiddenFields:Array):void

{

 editor.attributeInspector.formFieldsOrder =

 "fieldInspector";
 var layer:Layer;
 var fLayer:FeatureLayer;
 layer = map.getLayer(editableLayerName);

 //if layer is null, you entered the wrong name in the layername tag of the specific   editablelayer
 if(!layer) return;
 fLayer = layer

 as FeatureLayer;
 var field:FieldInspector;
 var fieldHidden:FieldInspector;
 // Setup FieldInspectors for visible fields
 // Assumption: both editableLayerFieldNames and editableLayerFieldLabels will have the  same number of elements
 for (var i:Number = 0; i < editableLayerFieldNames.length; i++)
 {

 field =

 new FieldInspector();
 field.featureLayer = fLayer;

 field.fieldName = editableLayerFieldNames[i];

 field.label = editableLayerFieldLabels[i];

 editor.attributeInspector.fieldInspectors.push(field);

 }

// Setup FieldInspectors for hidden fields
for (var j:Number = 0; j < editableLayerHiddenFields.length; j++)
{

fieldHidden =

new FieldInspector();
fieldHidden.featureLayer = fLayer;

fieldHidden.fieldName = editableLayerHiddenFields[j];

fieldHidden.visible =

false;
editor.attributeInspector.fieldInspectors.push(fieldHidden);

}

}





var editablelayers:XMLList = configXML.editablelayers as XMLList;
var editableLayerFieldNames:Array;
var editableLayerFieldLabels:Array;
var editableLayerHiddenFields:Array;
for each(var eLayer:XML in editablelayers.children())
{

if (eLayer.fieldnames.length() > 0)
{

// add field names to array
editableLayerFieldNames = [];

const tempFieldArray:Array = eLayer.fieldnames.split(",");
for (var count1:Number = 0; count1 < tempFieldArray.length; count1++)
{

editableLayerFieldNames.push(tempFieldArray[count1]);

}

}

if (eLayer.fieldlabels.length() > 0)
{

 // add field labels to array
editableLayerFieldLabels = [];

 const tempLabelArray:Array = eLayer.fieldlabels.split(",");
for (var counter2:Number = 0; counter2 < tempLabelArray.length; counter2++)
{

 editableLayerFieldLabels.push(tempLabelArray[counter2]);

 }

}

if (eLayer.fieldlabels.length() > 0)
{

// add names of hidden fields to array
editableLayerHiddenFields = [];

const tempHiddenFieldArray:Array = eLayer.hiddenfields.split(",");
for (var count3:Number = 0; count3 < tempHiddenFieldArray.length; count3++)
{

editableLayerHiddenFields.push(tempHiddenFieldArray[count3]);

}

}

  createFieldInspectors(eLayer.layername,editableLayerFieldNames,editableLayerFieldLabels,editableLayerHiddenFields);

}

}

 map.addEventListener(MapEvent.LAYER_ADD, mapLayerAddHandler,

 false);
 map.addEventListener(MapEvent.LAYER_REMOVE, mapLayerRemoveHandler,

 false);
 map.addEventListener(MapEvent.LAYER_REORDER, mapLayerReorderHandler,

 false);
 map.infoWindow.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, infoWindowCloseHandler);

 AppEvent.dispatch(AppEvent.DATA_OPT_LAYERS,

 null, getOplayers);
 mapLayers = map.layers

 as ArrayCollection;
 arrLayers = getLayers(mapLayers);

 // get all the layers on map except basemap layers;
 populateEditor(arrLayers);

 }
```

And here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- If compiling this widget, make sure to add -keep-all-type-selectors=true to your compiler arguments in the FB project properties. -->

    <configuration>
    <createoptions>
      <polygondrawtools>polygon,freehandpolygon,extent,autocomplete,circle,ellipse</polygondrawtools>
     <polylinedrawtools>polyline,freehandpolyline,line</polylinedrawtools>
    </createoptions>
    <addfeatures>true</addfeatures>
    <deletefeatures>true</deletefeatures>
    <updateattributes>true</updateattributes>
    <updategeometry>true</updategeometry>
    <toolbarvisible>true</toolbarvisible>
    <toolbarcutvisible>false</toolbarcutvisible>
    <toolbarmergevisible>false</toolbarmergevisible>
    <toolbarreshapevisible>false</toolbarreshapevisible>
    <editablelayers>
    <editablelayer>
    <layername>Bomen</layername>
    <fieldnames>Datum_Opname,Afstand_Tot_Hart_Spoor,Kilometer,Diameter,Type,Toestand,Status,Opmerking</fieldnames>
    <fieldlabels>Datum Opname,Afstand Tot Hart  Spoor,Kilometer,Diameter,Type,Toestand,Status,Opmerking</fieldlabels>
    <hiddenfields>OBJECTID</hiddenfields>
    </editablelayer>
    <editablelayer>
    <layername>Sloten</layername>
    <fieldnames>Waterschap,Jaar,GEMEENTE,EIGENAAR,Gereed,Datum_Gereed,Opmerking</fieldnames>
    <fieldlabels>Waterschap,Jaar,Gemeente,Eigenaar,Gereed,Datum Gereed,Opmerking</fieldlabels>
    <hiddenfields>OBJECTID</hiddenfields>
    </editablelayer>
    </editablelayers>
    <excludelayer>Infrabeheerder</excludelayer>
    <excludelayer>Spoortoegang</excludelayer>
    <!-- dit was in de comments tot showeditdatefield -->
    <formfieldsorder>fieldInspector</formfieldsorder>
    <showcreatorfield>true</showcreatorfield>
    <showcreationdatefield>true</showcreationdatefield>
    <showeditorfield>true</showeditorfield>
    <showeditdatefield>true</showeditdatefield>
    </configuration>
```

**EDIT**

I Fixed the problem when the popup didnt had any attributes that was because of the  property, the problem i need to fix is with the add attachment when i add all the attributes, or maybe an option to hide the layers, because when i turn off the excludelayer i get to see all the layers. Any help would be appreciated